# How to Select All Elements with a Selector in Polymer 2.x

Tags: css-selectors, polymer

I am trying to select all elements with `class="test"` in Polymer 2.x but am running into issues.

`document.querySelectorAll('.test')` selects nothing

`document.body.querySelectorAll('.test')` selects nothing

`this.querySelectorAll('.test')` selects nothing

`this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.test')` only selects the first matching node on the page

Note: these are all rendered in a single document, and don't need to break the shadow DOM layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `shadowRoot` is also supporting `querySelectorAll` method (with **All**) in the end, which *should* return NodeList with all items matched that query.

For example, if you open Polymer News App, which uses shadowDom:

https://news-docs.polymer-project.org/

and run query:

`document.querySelector('docs-app').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.tab');`

it returns 3 items for me.

So, in you case, please try the following:

`this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.test');`